# 'Data.Repository.UnitofWork' does not implement interface member 'Data.Repository.IUnitofWork.Customer'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I have one interface that declare other interface as property

```
namespace Data.Repository
{
    interface IUnitofWork : IDisposable
    {
        ICustomer Customer { get; }
        int Complete();

    }
}
```

I trying to implement this interface in UnitofWork class

```
namespace Data.Repository
{
    public class UnitofWork : IUnitofWork
    {
        private readonly NORTHWNDEntities _context;

        public UnitofWork(NORTHWNDEntities context)
        {
            _context = context;
            customer = new  CustomerRepository(_context);

        }

        public ICustomer customer { get; private set; }


        public int Complete()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

But it Shows Error in compile time
Error:'Data.Repository.UnitofWork' does not implement interface member 'Data.Repository.IUnitofWork.Customer'

please help me to solve this error
Thank You

Comment: You have a case typo in --- public ICustomer **C**ustomer { get; private set; } ---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's case sensitive. This, in your class:

```
public ICustomer customer { get; private set; }
```

Needs to be

```
public ICustomer Customer { get; private set; }
```

(capital C, because that is what is on your interface)

Comment: @ShahNIral Glad to be of help - don't forget to [mark this as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). :-)

Comment: You've upvoted (the up arrow which will have gone orange), accepting is the tick next to the answer, click that and it should go green. :-)